# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ not booting up and SD Card socket overheating

Tags: pi-3b+, sd-card, boot-issues, power-light

My Pi has been working fine up until a few hours ago. These are some of the the problems I’m facing:

1. On the Pi, the red power light is on but the yellow light isn’t.
2. There is no display on my monitor which is connected to the Pi HDMI port
3. When I connect my mouse to the USB port, the red power light on the underside of my mouse does not light up.
4. The SD card socket also heats up really quickly whenever I insert my original SD card in. I tried changing to a blank SD card; SD card socket
   does not heat up but still no display on the monitor and no yellow light.

Anybody knows what’s wrong with my raspberry pi?

Comment: what happened "a few hours ago" - was the pi on and you rebooted? did you update? have you tried writing an OS to the blank SD card? Do you mean green LED?

Comment: Your SDCard is trash - this is a common failure with the cheap Chinese fake cards. Write RaspiOS Buster on the new SDCard and see if that boots.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your original SD Card is broken, maybe with a short (short circuit). Only inserting a blank new SD Card into the card slot only verifies that it doesn't heat up and should be electrical ok. You need an operating system on it to boot it up. Just flash a current [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) of your choice to it and boot it in your RasPi.

Comment: pls review my edit as I guessed you meant the SD card might have a `short` - as in short circuit.